# "Умильный" и "умилительный"

Tags: семантика, синонимы, лексическая-сочетаемость

Слова ***умильный*** и ***умилительный*** являются синонимами, но не полными. Мне интересно, насколько "широка" их синонимичность. Например, можно ли в выражениях *умилительный вид, умилительное зрелище, умилительный ребенок* слово ***умилительный*** заменить словом ***умильный***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Они синонимичны в значении"вызывающий умиление": вызывающий умиление,выражающий умиление,приводящий в умиление, трогательный, умильный = нежный, приятный.Причём умильный как нежный, приятный - устаревшее значение (по Ожегову)

А вот второе, современное значение слова "умильный" — "льстивый, угодливый". У него другие синонимы: елейный,ласковый, приторно-ласковый, проникнутый умилением, сахарный,сладкий.Умильные речи, умильная улыбка. Вероятно, и умильный вид тоже может быть, а вот зрелище и ребёнок - только умилительные